# How can I hide resource forks and other special files in a workspace in Xcode 4's project navigator?

Tags: xcode4

I've noticed the resource forks (`._filename`) and other hidden files like `._.DS_Store` are shown in the project navigator when working on a "Workspace" project (Ruby).

How can configure Xcode 4 to not display these files in the project navigator?