# Don't display .pyc files in the Xcode 4 project navigator

Tags: python, xcode

I'm working on a fairly large django-project in Xcode 4. I prefer not to see all the automatically generated .pyc files in the project navigator.

Does anyone know a way to hide the .pyc files from the interface?

I don't necessarily want to remove them from disk.

Thanks.

-

What fails:

1. Checking "Show only files with source-control status" hides all files except the .pyc files... If only there is a way to invert this selection.
2. Showing files with matching name will also only give me a solution for solely showing the .pyc files. Typing ".py" also yields .pyc files...

Comment: Your issue duplicates this one: [how-can-i-hide-resource-forks-and-other-special-files-in-a-workspace-in-xcode-4s][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371963/how-can-i-hide-resource-forks-and-other-special-files-in-a-workspace-in-xcode-4s

Answer (score 1):

The best I can come with is the way I do it: By dragging only the .py files into the XCode project at the start. It's not ideal; there should be a way to filter out build files. This method also isn't great for sub-folders, since you have to create each folder and then drag the .py files in for each folder by hand. But it works, and now I have no .pyc files in my project. Also, irritatingly, I can't delete .pyc files from the project once they're in there, so controlling things from the outset is the only solution I found.

Answer (score 0):

given that this has not been answered directly here is an alternative solution using another programming software which is Coda 2.

You can create a rule that will hide those files, here is how to proceed :

- First open your preferences from the main menu
- Second go to the rules tab and create a new rule using the lower left "+" button
- Give the rule a name, such as "Python compiled Files"
- Select "Hide" from the right menu instead of "Skip"
- Edit the first rule as showed to apply it to files which "Name" ends with "pyc"
- Close the preferences pane and voilà, you are all set to keep being an efficient Coda user

This is taken from [this website](http://www.guideapolis.fr/en/pyc/) for sourcing purpose. It contains images illustrating this.